# Can someone please tell me the solution in the simplest way possible?

Tags: wordpress, deprecated, customizer

```
(Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property Sydney_Custom_CSS::$customizer_js is deprecated in /home/vol8_5/epizy.com/epiz_34347250/htdocs/wp-content/themes/sydney/inc/styles.php on line 33)
```

This is the error showing in Wordpress and I have opened my file manager and have this:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() { 
    $this->customizer_js = array();
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'print_styles' ) );
}
```

Someone please help this as I don't know how to solve it since i am not from a computers background.

I haven't tried anything as once before another error occurred different from this and I tried to solve but but then my website won't open so now I am asking for help instead of experimenting with it.

Comment: There's nothing to solve or fix for you. The theme `Sydney`, which you did not create, is just saying that the way a `property` is being created is no longer supported. This will not break your website. The theme developers need to fix this. https://athemes.com/support/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP doesn't need to fix this. This is going to be an issue with a theme developer.

Comment: If you have old version of theme then please update theme